What's the most efficient way to stream data to S3 using aioboto3
I'm trying to implement a true streaming solution from an API to S3 using aioboto3. The data flow is:

Fetch data from API using pagination (each page returns N items)
Stream each item directly to S3
The final file should be compressed (currently using gzip) and in JSON format

My current approach uses put_object which requires building the entire content in memory:
async with session.client('s3') as s3:
    await s3.put_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key,
        Body=json_content,  # This holds everything in memory
        ContentType='application/json',
        ContentEncoding='gzip'
    )

I'd expect something like this to be possible:
async def fetch_data() -> AsyncIterator[dict]:
    """Fetch paginated data from API."""
    while has_more_pages:
        items = await fetch_page()
        for item in items:
            yield item

async def stream_to_s3():
    async with s3.client() as client:
        # Some streaming method that handles compression
        await client.stream_to_s3(
            data_stream=fetch_data(),
            bucket=bucket,
            key=key,
            compression='gzip'
        )

I see that aioboto3 has upload_fileobj and multipart upload capabilities, but I'm not sure what's the most efficient way to achieve true streaming without buffering everything in memory.
What's the state-of-the-art approach for streaming data to S3 using aioboto3? The data size can be anywhere from a few KB to several GB.
